# Given the wavefunction of an electron in hydrogen, what possible energies can it obtain and what are the probabilities of those energies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, orbitals

we are given, $$\psi(\textbf{r})=A\left[R_{2,1}(r)Y_{1,-1}(\theta,\phi)+iR_{2,1}(r)Y_{1,0}(\theta,\phi)+2R_{2,1}(r)Y_{1,1}(\theta,\phi)\right]$$ we can rewrite this as: $$\left|\psi(\textbf{r})\right>=A\left[\left|\psi_{2,1,-1}\right>+i\left|\psi_{2,1,0}\right>+2\left|\psi_{2,1,1}\right>\right]$$

I know that I have to find the normalizations constant so, \begin{align*}
1&=\left<\psi(\textbf{r})|\psi(\textbf{r})\right>\\
&=A^2\left(1^2+1^2+2^2\right)\\
&=A^2(6)\\
\Rightarrow A&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}.
\end{align*}

So the probability of being in Each state is: 
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(\left|\psi_{2,1,-1}\right>)&=|c_n|^2=\frac{1}{6}\\
    \mathbb{P}(\left|\psi_{2,1,0}\right>)&=\frac{1}{6}\\
    \mathbb{P}(\left|\psi_{2,1,1}\right>)&=\frac{4}{6}\\
\end{align*}

But from here how do i get the energy? since $n=2$ for all cases do i just use the  formula? $$E_n=-\left[\frac{m}{2\hbar^2}\left(\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\right)^2\right]\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{E_1}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". Can you see why if I remind you:

> A measurement of the energy will leave your system in one of the eigenstates $|\psi_{\alpha}\rangle$ of the Hamiltonian. If the system starts out in the state $|\psi\rangle$, the probability that the system will be in the state $|\psi_{\alpha}\rangle$ afterwards is given by $P(\alpha) = | \langle \psi | \psi_{\alpha}\rangle |^2$. The energy measured in that case is $E(\alpha) = \langle \psi_\alpha | H |\psi_{\alpha}\rangle$. The expectation value for the energy is $\sum_\alpha P(\alpha) E(\alpha)$.

Comment: So the probability of getting the energy associated with each state is 1 since they all have the same energy, because of course when you measure the energy of our state $\left|\psi(\mathbf{r})\right>$ we will always get $E_2$ since that is the only energy allowed for each 'component'. Is that correct reasoning?

Comment: @AlexSampson Sounds correct!